# Wordpress Doubts

Tags: php, html

Hai

I want to build a wordpress in my localhost, Is it possible to test this in My local system which is Windows 2000

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: You have been asked several times before to be more specific in your questions/question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to PHP and wordpress then you can start with [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). You can also host wordpress using IIS and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is, just install Apache, PHP and MySQL on your computer and follow up Wordpress installation procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You download [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), and put wordpress in htdocs and install it.

Or you can use WAMP as well.

Answer (score 0):

go download wordpress [there](http://wordpress.org/download/) and take a look at the readme.html into the package file.

I think if you are on windows you should install [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), on linux lamp.